# Calculate concurrent sessions with T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, concurrency

I have the date of sesions in my database (start and end of session) in datatime type. I need to calculate how many concurrent sessions has been done in a concrete time and per user type. It means I need to compute the number of simultaneous sessions per user and per day.

The database use SQL Server and the table is like the next:

```
SESSION GRU_ID      SES_INI                 SES_END
233550  Enfermeros  2016-02-10 07:49:32.000 2016-02-10 14:51:46.000
233551  Enfermeros  2016-02-10 07:57:05.000 2016-02-10 12:37:03.000
233552  Enfermeros  2016-02-10 08:03:09.000 2016-02-10 14:44:30.000
233553  Enfermeros  2016-02-10 08:04:49.000 2016-02-10 13:22:58.000
233556  Enfermeros  2016-02-10 08:06:52.000 2016-02-10 14:54:29.000
233559  Enfermeros  2016-02-10 08:08:00.000 2016-02-10 10:49:38.000
233560  Enfermeros  2016-02-10 08:08:09.000 2016-02-10 14:25:19.000
233564  Enfermeros  2016-02-10 08:13:54.000 2016-02-10 14:51:19.000
233565  Enfermeros  2016-02-10 08:14:35.000 2016-02-10 11:46:16.000
233567  Enfermeros  2016-02-10 08:16:01.000 2016-02-10 15:05:20.000
233568  Enfermeros  2016-02-10 08:17:01.000 2016-02-10 12:40:05.000
233569  Enfermeros  2016-02-10 08:19:13.000 2016-02-10 14:46:54.000
233570  Enfermeros  2016-02-10 08:17:50.000 2016-02-10 14:48:10.000
233579  Enfermeros  2016-02-10 08:29:52.000 2016-02-10 14:21:38.000
233580  Enfermeros  2016-02-10 08:31:11.000 2016-02-10 10:09:36.000
233584  Enfermeros  2016-02-10 08:38:52.000 2016-02-10 13:22:06.000
233585  Enfermeros  2016-02-10 08:40:11.000 2016-02-10 11:08:10.000
233589  Enfermeros  2016-02-10 08:48:09.000 2016-02-11 16:59:06.000
233603  Enfermeros  2016-02-10 09:24:56.000 2016-02-10 09:37:29.000
233607  Enfermeros  2016-02-10 09:29:31.000 2016-02-10 16:00:31.000
233623  Enfermeros  2016-02-10 10:08:34.000 2016-02-10 12:16:28.000
233624  Enfermeros  2016-02-10 10:09:36.000 2016-02-10 10:10:27.000
233625  Enfermeros  2016-02-10 10:10:51.000 2016-02-10 10:46:30.000
```

The select I'm using is the next. The problem is that this select summarizes al the sessions that have ocurred during this interval of time between ses_ini and ses_end, but it does not mean simultaneous sessions.

```
SELECT  GRU_ID AS TIPO_USUARIO, count(GRU_ID) AS TOTAL
FROM 
        dbo.USUARIOS INNER JOIN
        dbo.SESIONES ON dbo.USUARIOS.CODIGOUSUARIO = dbo.SESIONES.CODIGOUSUARIO INNER JOIN
        dbo.GRUPOS ON dbo.USUARIOS.CODIGOGRUPO = dbo.GRUPOS.CODIGOGRUPO
WHERE 
        SES_FECHAFIN BETWEEN @SES_INI AND @SES_END AND
        DAY(ses_fechainicio) = 10 AND MONTH(ses_INI)= 2 AND YEAR(ses_END) = 2016 AND ses_duracion IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY GRU_ID
```

I need some kind of algorithm to calculate all simultaneous sessions with this data.

EDIT:

If I have something like this:

```
Session A: 9.00 - 10.00
Session B: 9.00 - 9.30
Session C: 9.30 - 9.45
Session D: 9.40 - 10:00
```

Between the first Session A, There are the next simultaneous sessions: A-B and A-C-D (Sessions B and C I don't consider simultaneous) 
With the select I did, I get all sessions between 9.00-10.00, that is 4, but I really need to get the maximum of simultaneous sessions, that is 3, and I need to do the same for each sessions.

The complete script I did is like this:

One loop (while) for years, one for months and other for days (nested loops). Then one cursor which select all the sessions for a day(using the loops). Once I get all the sessions per days, I make an insert(with the select I pasted) which populate a table with 5 columns: Simultanious sessions, GRU_ID(type of user: Physician,administrator, nurse, etc)day, month and year. The problem is with the insert, because I can only get the total number of sessions between each session, but not the simultaneous sessions. Sorry if I dont explain well, but is difficult and my english is not very good....

Comment: could you post output you need based on input you  pasted.

Comment: I added more details in my question

Comment: it would be helpfull,if you can add at how you arrived at output based on data you pasted

Comment: It is more complex that the data I pasted. The table contanis more than 1.000.000 of rows (more than 3 years of data), and there are more than one kind of user (GRU_ID). What I really want is to get, at least, two columns:
-The max of simultaneous connections per day and per GRU_ID
-The GRU_ID.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to put all the times in one big list with a `+1` for session starts and a `-1` for session ends.  Then a cumulative sum is pretty close to what you want.

So:

```
select gru_id, dt,
       sum(val) over (partition by gru_id order by dt) as concurrent_sessions
from ((select gru_id, ses_ini as dt, 1 as val from t
      ) union all
      (select gru_id, ses_end, -1 as val from t
      )
     ) g;
```

This gives the number for each time in the data.  You probably want to summarize it somehow.  Your existing question is not clear on this point -- you should ask another question if you want to specify a particular output.

This is "close" in the sense of handling ties.  If a user starts and stops sessions at exactly the same time, there might be an "off-by-one" error, depending on how you want to count the sessions.

Comment: If one session start at the same time other user stops a session, I don't want to consider it as simultaneous

Comment: Thanks for your help. I used your script over the table but I'm getting values like:
concurrent_sessions -79, -78 -77

In negative. Is not possible to have all this simultaneous sessions because the concurrent license is max 30.

Comment: @user3795094 . . . The results include the `gru_id` and the times, so you can verify what is happening against the original data.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this... Count the number of sessions that start or end during another session.  Then summarize by date and max count.

```
SELECT
    [GRU_ID]
    ,CAST([Ses_Ini] AS DATE) AS [Date]
    ,MAX([Sessions Count]) AS [Max Connections]
FROM (
    SELECT 
        [Data].[Session]
        ,[Data].[GRU_ID]
        ,[Data].[Ses_Ini]
        ,[Data].[Ses_End]
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT [D2].[Session]) AS [Sessions Count]
    FROM [Data]
    INNER JOIN [Data] AS [D2]
        ON ([d2].[Ses_Ini] BETWEEN [Data].[Ses_Ini] AND [Data].[Ses_End])
            OR ([d2].[Ses_End] BETWEEN [Data].[Ses_Ini] AND [Data].[Ses_End])
    GROUP BY 
        [Data].[Session]
        ,[Data].[GRU_ID]
        ,[Data].[Ses_Ini]
        ,[Data].[Ses_End]
) AS [SessionCounts]
GROUP BY
    [GRU_ID]
    ,CAST([Ses_Ini] AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that sessions are concurrent if `ses_ini` of new session is between `ses_ini` and `ses_end` of another session.
This is implementation:

```
create table #sess([session] int,gru_id varchar(20),ses_ini datetime,ses_end datetime)

insert #sess
values
(233550,  'Enfermeros',  '2016-02-10 07:49:32.000', '2016-02-10 14:51:46.000'),
(233551  ,'Enfermeros',  '2016-02-10 07:57:05.000', '2016-02-10 12:37:03.000'),
(233552  ,'Enfermeros',  '2016-02-10 08:03:09.000', '2016-02-10 14:44:30.000'),
(233553  ,'Enfermeros',  '2016-02-10 08:04:49.000', '2016-02-10 13:22:58.000'),
(233556  ,'Enfermeros',  '2016-02-10 08:06:52.000', '2016-02-10 14:54:29.000'),
(233559  ,'Enfermeros',  '2016-02-10 08:08:00.000', '2016-02-10 10:49:38.000'),
(233560  ,'Enfermeros',  '2016-02-10 08:08:09.000', '2016-02-10 14:25:19.000'),
(233564  ,'Enfermeros',  '2016-02-10 08:13:54.000', '2016-02-10 14:51:19.000'),
(233565  ,'Enfermeros',  '2016-02-10 08:14:35.000', '2016-02-10 11:46:16.000'),
(233567  ,'Enfermeros',  '2016-02-10 08:16:01.000', '2016-02-10 15:05:20.000'),
(233568  ,'Enfermeros',  '2016-02-10 08:17:01.000', '2016-02-10 12:40:05.000'),
(233569  ,'Enfermeros',  '2016-02-10 08:19:13.000', '2016-02-10 14:46:54.000'),
(233570  ,'Enfermeros',  '2016-02-10 08:17:50.000', '2016-02-10 14:48:10.000'),
(233579  ,'Enfermeros',  '2016-02-10 08:29:52.000', '2016-02-10 14:21:38.000'),
(233580  ,'Enfermeros',  '2016-02-10 08:31:11.000', '2016-02-10 10:09:36.000'),
(233584  ,'Enfermeros',  '2016-02-10 08:38:52.000', '2016-02-10 13:22:06.000'),
(233585  ,'Enfermeros',  '2016-02-10 08:40:11.000', '2016-02-10 11:08:10.000'),
(233589  ,'Enfermeros',  '2016-02-10 08:48:09.000', '2016-02-11 16:59:06.000'),
(233603  ,'Enfermeros',  '2016-02-10 09:24:56.000', '2016-02-10 09:37:29.000'),
(233607  ,'Enfermeros',  '2016-02-10 09:29:31.000', '2016-02-10 16:00:31.000'),
(233623  ,'Enfermeros',  '2016-02-10 10:08:34.000', '2016-02-10 12:16:28.000'),
(233624  ,'Enfermeros',  '2016-02-10 10:09:36.000', '2016-02-10 10:10:27.000'),
(233625  ,'Enfermeros',  '2016-02-10 10:10:51.000', '2016-02-10 10:46:30.000')

--select all concurrent sessions
select s.session,s1.session s1_sess,s.ses_ini,s.ses_end,s1.ses_ini s1_ini
from #sess s
inner join #sess s1 on s1.ses_ini >= s.ses_ini and s1.ses_ini < s.ses_end and s.session<>s1.session
order by 1

-- calculate the number of concurrent sessions
;with ss as (
select s.session,s1.session s1_sess,s.ses_ini,s.ses_end,s1.ses_ini s1_ini
from #sess s
inner join #sess s1 on s1.ses_ini >= s.ses_ini and s1.ses_ini < s.ses_end and s.session<>s1.session
)
select session, count(s1_sess) cnt
from ss
group by session
order by 2 desc
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Update + addition:

```
declare @dtStart datetime, @dtEnd datetime

select @dtStart= convert(varchar(13),(select min(ses_ini) from #sess), 120)+':00:00' 
,@dtEnd= convert(varchar(13),dateadd(hh,1,(select max(ses_end) from #sess)), 120)+':00:00' 

;with tm as (
select 1 num, @dtStart sesStart, dateadd(hh,1,@dtStart) sesEnd
union all
select num+1,dateadd(hh,1,sesStart),dateadd(hh,1,sesEnd)
from tm where tm.sesStart<@dtEnd
)
select 'sess '+cast(num as varchar) sess,sesStart,sesEnd, count(session) cnt
from tm
inner join #sess s on (s.ses_ini>=tm.sesStart and s.ses_ini < tm.sesEnd) or 
(s.ses_end>tm.sesStart and s.ses_end <= tm.sesEnd)
group by num,sesStart,sesEnd
```

Result:

```
sess    sesStart                sesEnd                  cnt
sess 1  2016-02-10 07:00:00.000 2016-02-10 08:00:00.000 2
sess 2  2016-02-10 08:00:00.000 2016-02-10 09:00:00.000 16
sess 3  2016-02-10 09:00:00.000 2016-02-10 10:00:00.000 2
sess 4  2016-02-10 10:00:00.000 2016-02-10 11:00:00.000 5
sess 5  2016-02-10 11:00:00.000 2016-02-10 12:00:00.000 2
sess 6  2016-02-10 12:00:00.000 2016-02-10 13:00:00.000 3
sess 7  2016-02-10 13:00:00.000 2016-02-10 14:00:00.000 2
sess 8  2016-02-10 14:00:00.000 2016-02-10 15:00:00.000 8
sess 9  2016-02-10 15:00:00.000 2016-02-10 16:00:00.000 1
sess 10 2016-02-10 16:00:00.000 2016-02-10 17:00:00.000 1
sess 34 2016-02-11 16:00:00.000 2016-02-11 17:00:00.000 1
```

Update 2: Sessions which exist during each time interval

```
declare @dtStart datetime, @dtEnd datetime

select @dtStart= convert(varchar(13),(select min(ses_ini) from #sess), 120)+':00:00' 
,@dtEnd= convert(varchar(13),dateadd(hh,1,(select max(ses_end) from #sess)), 120)+':00:00' 

;with tm as (
select 1 num, @dtStart sesStart, dateadd(hh,1,@dtStart) sesEnd
union all
select num+1,dateadd(hh,1,sesStart),dateadd(hh,1,sesEnd)
from tm where tm.sesStart<@dtEnd
)
select 'sess '+cast(num as varchar) sess,sesStart,sesEnd, count(session) cnt
from tm
inner join #sess s on (s.ses_end > tm.sesStart and s.ses_ini <= tm.sesEnd) 
group by num,sesStart,sesEnd
```

Results:

```
sess    sesStart            sesEnd              cnt
sess 1  2016-02-10 07:00:00 2016-02-10 08:00:00 2
sess 2  2016-02-10 08:00:00 2016-02-10 09:00:00 18
sess 3  2016-02-10 09:00:00 2016-02-10 10:00:00 20
sess 4  2016-02-10 10:00:00 2016-02-10 11:00:00 22
sess 5  2016-02-10 11:00:00 2016-02-10 12:00:00 18
sess 6  2016-02-10 12:00:00 2016-02-10 13:00:00 16
sess 7  2016-02-10 13:00:00 2016-02-10 14:00:00 13
sess 8  2016-02-10 14:00:00 2016-02-10 15:00:00 11
sess 9  2016-02-10 15:00:00 2016-02-10 16:00:00 3
sess 10 2016-02-10 16:00:00 2016-02-10 17:00:00 2
sess 11 2016-02-10 17:00:00 2016-02-10 18:00:00 1
sess 12 2016-02-10 18:00:00 2016-02-10 19:00:00 1
sess 13 2016-02-10 19:00:00 2016-02-10 20:00:00 1
sess 14 2016-02-10 20:00:00 2016-02-10 21:00:00 1
sess 15 2016-02-10 21:00:00 2016-02-10 22:00:00 1
sess 16 2016-02-10 22:00:00 2016-02-10 23:00:00 1
sess 17 2016-02-10 23:00:00 2016-02-11 00:00:00 1
sess 18 2016-02-11 00:00:00 2016-02-11 01:00:00 1
sess 19 2016-02-11 01:00:00 2016-02-11 02:00:00 1
sess 20 2016-02-11 02:00:00 2016-02-11 03:00:00 1
sess 21 2016-02-11 03:00:00 2016-02-11 04:00:00 1
sess 22 2016-02-11 04:00:00 2016-02-11 05:00:00 1
sess 23 2016-02-11 05:00:00 2016-02-11 06:00:00 1
sess 24 2016-02-11 06:00:00 2016-02-11 07:00:00 1
sess 25 2016-02-11 07:00:00 2016-02-11 08:00:00 1
sess 26 2016-02-11 08:00:00 2016-02-11 09:00:00 1
sess 27 2016-02-11 09:00:00 2016-02-11 10:00:00 1
sess 28 2016-02-11 10:00:00 2016-02-11 11:00:00 1
sess 29 2016-02-11 11:00:00 2016-02-11 12:00:00 1
sess 30 2016-02-11 12:00:00 2016-02-11 13:00:00 1
sess 31 2016-02-11 13:00:00 2016-02-11 14:00:00 1
sess 32 2016-02-11 14:00:00 2016-02-11 15:00:00 1
sess 33 2016-02-11 15:00:00 2016-02-11 16:00:00 1
sess 34 2016-02-11 16:00:00 2016-02-11 17:00:00 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It is near to be the solution I need. The only think is missing is that I need to get the count of each connection as concurrent. I mean, I need to know how many people are connected for each session. If for example there are 3 sessions: 
Session A: 09:00 - 10:00
Session B: 09:10 - 10:00
Session C: 09:11 - 10:00

There are a maximum of 2 concurrent sessions, but with your implementation I only get 1, beacause is not taking into account itself session. I need to know for each session all the users that were connected simultaneously (GRU_ID and total of concurrent sessions)

Comment: So edit my solution according to your requirements.  Is my solution acceptable?

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help but, I checked your script and is not working properly. What I'm getting is all the sessions between one session, but notice that it does not mean that this sessions are simultaneous... Im getting more than 1480 concurrent sessions an is impossible...

Comment: @user3795094 Did you check my last update? I think it returns exactly what you want: the number of sessions which started **before** end of time slot and **after** start of time slot.